# Prevent input.change when clearAll is clicked, isotope filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I have setup an isotope filtering with multiple checkbox groups and also a select form. I also added a "clearAll" button underneath the filter groups that clears all checkboxes and reset the select to zero (show all).

I realized that when i click this button, a change event is detected on the checkboxes and the select form, and the `$input.change` function is executed on the filter groups, which is performance-wise unwise. I just want to apply `filter: '*'` to my isotope container and not go through all the `$input.change(function(){})`.

```
    ($container = $('#grid')), ($input = $('#filters input, #filters select'));
    $checkboxes = $('#filters input');
    $select = $('#filters.top-filters select');
    $clearAll = $('.clear_all');

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.products',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    });

    $input.change(function () {
      [...My filtering code...]
    }); 

    $clearAll.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
        $select.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        $container.isotope({ filter: '*' });
    });
```

Any idea on how I could restrict the `$input.change` function only to user interaction?

Edit : i tried to wrap the execution with a variable condition, but it still seems to run.

```
    ($container = $('#grid')), ($input = $('#filters input, #filters select'));
    $checkboxes = $('#filters input');
    $select = $('#filters.top-filters select');
    $clearAll = $('.clear_all');

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.products',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    });
    
    let execute = true;
    if(execute) {
      $input.change(function () {
        [...My filtering code...]
      });
    }

    $clearAll.on('click', function (e) {
        execute = false;
        
        e.preventDefault();
        $checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
        $select.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        $container.isotope({ filter: '*' });
        
        execute = true;
    });
```

Comment: May be you can enable or disable input change event execution by flag.
Ex. When clearAll pressed, flag set to false, then change event doesn't pertorm at all.
It it's true, then it will perform.

In this case, you need to set flag true, when focus on input.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, i edited my post taking in consideration your advice, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Not sure how you would have managed to get it working that way to begin with - changing field values _via_ script, does not normally trigger any event handlers in the first place. _"I realized that when i click this button, a change event is detected on the checkboxes and the select form"_ - is it _really_, have you verified that? Or did you just assume it would happen?

Comment: I had performance issues when clicking that clearAll button, so I recorded a trace in chrome, and I thought i've seen some of the execution supposed to happen inside `input.change` when the button is clicked, but i'll check again.

Comment: Hi Xavier C, you need to add a condition within the change event, instead of an event within condition, so that way, your [...My filtering code...] will execute if condition is true.

Comment: Hey Ravi, thanks, could you give me a quick example ?